# FPC connector name

Tags: connector, fpc, ffc

I am trying to make microscope from my old Xiaomi Note 10. I made kiosk mode android app. But to make it really convenient I have to move camera away from screen.

So I am exploring options to make extension cable. (I guess there is no option to buy it)

One solution I see is to order flexible PCB. I am failing to find FPC connector names. Most are 24 pin and one is 30 pin.

I hope someone can tell me how to identify these FPC connectors. Or may be there are some extension cables already available.

Something similar connector seems to be `Molex SlimStack 0.4`

[image: Camera with FPC connector]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> FPC connector name

I call those "dual-beam board-to-board connectors". Digikey lumps them with "mezzanine connectors". Each manufacturer calls them something else, if anything at all.

> how to identify these FPC connectors

Please try my [Identiconn](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=dual_beam_b2b_conn).  Try the [great Digikey search engine](https://www.digikey.com/short/p0nh8v9r). To narrow it down, you will need to measure the exact pitch.

> there are some extension cables already available.

Unlikely. This is the kind of assembly you must make yourself by designing a flex circuit and having it manufactured (not cheap).

> options to make extension cable.

Be aware that that may not work: the added capacity of the cable and any discontinuous impedance in the traces may prevent high speed communications.

Comment: Thank You! Awesome website

Comment: Randomly extending the wires may not work. You should find out the pinout of the connectors, and like said in this answer, design a flex PCB with wires having specific differential and single-ended characteristic impedances over a ground plane, with possibly bypass caps on supply pins. And, the wires may still be too long to work.